# Validation on rails that permits first_name or last_name to be null but not both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, model, rspec-rails

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validate :first_or_last_name_null
  

  def first_or_last_name_null
    if first_name.nil? && last_name.nil?
        errors.add(:base, "either first_name or last_name must be present!")
    end
  end
```

**I don't know what is wrong in my lines of code to get the following error from rspec..**
Assignment rq11 Validators: allows a Profile with a null first name when last name present

```
 Failure/Error: expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>"Smith", :gender=>"male")).to be_valid
   expected `#<Profile id: nil, gender: "male", birth_year: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: "Smith", user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>.valid?` to return true, got false
```

The spec file has the following ..

```
context "rq11" do
      context "Validators:" do
        it "does not allow a User without a username" do
          expect(User.new(:username=> "")).to_not be_valid
        end

        it "does not allow a Profile with a null first and last name" do
          expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>nil, :gender=>"male")).to_not be_valid
        end
        it "allows a Profile with a null first name when last name present" do
          expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>"Smith", :gender=>"male")).to be_valid
        end
        it "allows a Profile with a null last name when first name present" do
          expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>"Joe", :last_name=>nil, :gender=>"male")).to be_valid
        end

        it "does not allow a Profile with a gender other than male or female " do
          expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>"first", :last_name=>"last", :gender=>"neutral")).to_not be_valid
        end
        it "does not allow a boy named Sue" do
          expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>"Sue", :last_name=>"last", :gender=>"male")).to_not be_valid
        end
        it "allows a Profile with gender male" do
          expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>"first", :last_name=>"last", :gender=>"male")).to be_valid
        end
        it "allows a Profile with gender female" do
          expect(Profile.new(:first_name=>"first", :last_name=>"last", :gender=>"female")).to be_valid
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: EDIT: I added the end class tag forgot to write it down here, and the error message is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Roman's answer is correct, I would like to add more details and more options to solve the issue.

Your `Profile` `belong_to :user`. Per default `belongs_to` associations require the associated object to exist. In this case, there must be a user associated with a profile otherwise the profile will not be valid.

You have three options to fix this issue, depending on your use-case:

1. Make the association optional, read about [optional `belongs_to` associations in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#optional). This obviously is only an option if it makes sense in the context of your application that there is no need for an association to always exist.

   ```
   belongs_to :user, optional: true
   ```

   `optional: true` disables the built-in validation.
2. You make sure that each profile in your spec has always a valid user assigned. Something like this might work:

   ```
   let(:user) { User.find_or_create_by(username: 'test_user') }

   it "does not allow a Profile with a null first and last name" do
     expect(Profile.new(user: user, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, gender: "male")).to_not be_valid
   end
   ```
3. You do not only test if an instance is valid, but instead, if there is an expected, specific error

   ```
   it "does not allow a Profile with a null first and last name" do
     profile = Profile.new(:first_name=>nil, :last_name=>nil, :gender=>"male")
     profile.valid? # trigger validations

     # with all Rails versions
     expect(profile.errors[:base]).to include "either first_name or last_name must be present!"

     # or with Rails >= 6:
     expect(profile.errors).to be_of_kind(:base, "either first_name or last_name must be present!")
   end
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I think it is not valid because `user_id` is empty. By default rails validates presence of associations as I remember. Add `user_id` to all profiles and it should be ok